# Try to upload .zip file using ftp_put function but it is not able to upload large file(more than 1 MB)

Tags: php

I am using the following code to upload a `.zip` file, but am unable to upload a file of size greater than 1MB:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $target_path.'/'.$filename, $source, FTP_BINARY);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: check your MAX POST SIZE

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the config settings at php.ini max_file_uploads to a latger value, the values are taken as MB so give something as large as 5

I am sure it should work.

Comment: I can not modify the settings of server php.ini file.
I am using the below settings in my code.
ini_set('post_max_size',"20M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize',"20M");

But it is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. changing in php.ini will result in php application that is running.
2. changing in htaccess file will result in project
3. changing in a php file will result in php file and its included files

Choosing which one is based on your recuirements.

Use, **upload_max_filesize** this will control the size of file to be uploaded.

**post_max_size** is the size of data posted in side form elements.

it could be file, input, checkbox... etc. So this also has to be altered based on file size.

You should adjust both **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** to perform file operation and others...

Comment: what was the error coming.. can you post that ? @Avinash Dahariya

Comment: Here ftp_put returns false value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked error_log . If not check that, and find out what exactly the problem is, and if using apache, you can set the php.ini setting in .htaccess . Like this

```
php_value  upload_max_filesize  20M
```

Paste this .htaccess file and you will be able to upload the file. Also,check error_log for exactly what is causing the issue.